# How can I open a file from Windows Explorer and load it into a rich text control?

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, file-format

I am writing a word processor in Visual Basic and I am trying to get my application to load a file opened from Windows Explorer. I found this code, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim s As String

    s = Command$()

    If s <> "" Then
        RichTextBox1.LoadFile(s)
    Else
        '
        ' Do something else since no file was specified
        ' 
    End If
End Sub
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getcommandlineargs). See the Remarks section.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an OpenFileDialog to simulate Windows explorer.

```
Private Sub FileToRTB()
    Dim fName As String = ""
    Dim d As New OpenFileDialog
    d.Filter = "Rich Text Files (*.rtf)|*.rtf"
    If d.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        fName = d.FileName
        RichTextBox1.LoadFile(fName)
    End If
End Sub
```